Double expansion
I am seeking help with finding a double infinite series expansion of the following integral expression, first in the limit of large $x$ and then in the limit of large $p$:
\begin{equation}
I= \int_0^\infty \frac{dq}{e^q-1} \frac{l^2 p^2-iz}{l^2 p^2 +iz} Ln\Big(\frac{l p-iz}{l p+iz}\Big)
\end{equation}
where $z = \sqrt{q^2 + 2iqx}$.
I am particularly interested in the expansions in the following order: First for large $x$ then for large $p$. I attempted to use the series expansion
$$
\log \left( \frac{z+1}{z-1} \right) = 2 \left( \frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{3z^3} + \frac{1}{5z^5} + \cdots \right)
$$
for $z>>1$, as given in Abramowitz and Stegun's book. However, this approach does not seem to provide the correct result.
Any assistance in deriving the correct double infinite series expansion would be greatly appreciated. There should be a closed formula for the double expansion!
Thank you!
